# Laravel docker. Миграции выполняются, api не работает

Tags: laravel, docker-compose

Собственно, проблема в заголовке. Миграции выполняются, в бд все вижу, но если стучусь по API
`localhost/api/v0.1/auth/signup` - получаю `"errorInfo": null` (в данном котроллере через Eloquent сохраняю юзера в бд). Ошибок никаких в логах не вижу.

Документация php по этому поводу говорит:

> Если не задан SQLSTATE код или драйвер не сообщил об ошибке, то
> элементы следующие за нулевым будут иметь значение NULL.

docker-compose

```
version: '3'
services:

  #PHP Service
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: app
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    environment:
      SERVICE_NAME: app
      SERVICE_TAGS: dev
    working_dir: /var/www
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www
      - ./docker/php/local.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/local.ini
    networks:
      - app-network

  #Nginx Service
  webserver:
    image: nginx:alpine
    container_name: webserver
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www
      - ./docker/nginx/conf.d/:/etc/nginx/conf.d/
    networks:
      - app-network

  #MySQL Service
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7.22
    container_name: db
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: test
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
      SERVICE_TAGS: dev
      SERVICE_NAME: mysql
    volumes:
      - dbdata:/var/lib/mysql/
      - ./docker/mysql/my.cnf:/etc/mysql/my.cnf
    networks:
      - app-network

#Docker Networks
networks:
  app-network:
    driver: bridge
#Volumes
volumes:
  dbdata:
    driver: local
```

.env

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=db
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=test
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=root
```

Пожалуйста, помогите!

**UPD** 
Обратная ситуация возникает, если в .env поменять DB_HOST с db на localhost. В таком случае API работает, но миграции не мигрируют, получаю ошибку:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed
```

Answer (score 0):

[Нашел решение.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56321315/laravel-docker-container-not-connecting-to-local-mysql)

В данном вопросе разбирается похожая проблема, лично мне помогло `DB_HOST=host.docker.internal`